# Anyway to change language setting for APIM on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I am doing some tests with "API Management" provided on Bluemix from US-south site.  However, it's hard for me to post questions with screenshots due to the information shown on web UI is in Chinese by default.

So please help me to change the language setting to English on Bluemix (APIM more specifically) if anyone knows how-to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring English as the first accept-languages should render the page in US locale.

**In Chrome:**

1. Close Chrome to prevent overriding the preferences file you are about to edit.
2. Open this file in the text editor:
   `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`
3. Lookup `accept_languages`.

   "intl": {
       "accept_languages": "en-US,en,ru"
   }
4. Make `en-US` or `en` to be the first one in the value.

**In Firefox:**

1. Open `about:config` page.
2. Lookup `intl.accept_languages`.
3. Change the value so that `en-US` or `en` to be the first one.

**In IE:**

1. Click Tools - Internet Options.
2. On General tab, click Languages.
3. In Language Preferences dialog, move English to the top.
4. Click OK.

Comment: For Chrome, why not just change it through the UI, `Settings -> Lanuages` ?

Comment: You can. Maybe that's easier way in this case. I was just used to this method because I used it to add a pseudo language that UI options does not provide.

Comment: I tried all of them, Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  Only Firefox works, but I can live with that for now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your browser preferences for "language" and make "English" the preferred language. Bluemix should pick up that setting when you reload the, e.g., dashboard page.